# HDMI out on a tablet doesn't work with a 17" LCD monitor

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, external-display, tablet

I have a problem getting HDMI out of my tablet playing nice with video inputs of an old 17" monitor. Monitor in question is [this](https://www.alza.cz/lcd-monitor-fujitsu-siemens-b17-5-d94542.htm#popis), and the tablet is [this](http://www.onda-tablet.com/onda-v820w-8-0-inch-ips-screen-win8-tablet-ram-2gb-bluetooth-4-0-hdmi.html). Monitor works just fine when connected to a PC and tablet is able to send an image to my main monitor, which is a 21" fullHD acer monitor, although it doesn't work with every microHDMI to DVI/VGA adapter, only some. When I use those same adapters that work to connect the 17" monitor with the tablet no input is detected by the monitor.

I read a little bit about this issue and the problem might be that I'm not using an active HDMI to VGA converter. Something [like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/141643127590?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT). Note that I tried both the VGA and the DVI connectors of the monitor, and none of them worked. Is there some other incompatibility that I'm missing that's causing the monitor not to detect any video inputs when connected to the tablet? I don't want to spend money on adapters if it's not possible for the tablet to work with this monitor. Thanks...

Comment: Could be due to HDCP, though I’m not sure whether it’s enforced in any way. Then there’s the fact that this monitor doesn’t support any HD resolutions.

Comment: @DanielB I don't think it's HDCP seeing how the same HDMI output works with my other monitor. And this 17" monitor has a native resolution of 1280X1024. The other option I get when I connect my desktop is 800X600, I think. So you think the resolution incompatibility might be the culprit?